# Excel XML table headings with spaces

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, ms-office, msxml

I'm exposing tables in my system via a webservice to use within Excel worksheets (as an XML Source). The tables can have headers that contain spaces and other characters not valid in XML element names. Excel is fine with that, and my system is fine with that, but the intermediate format (XML) is not.

So, can the XML Source tell Excel (via schema or data) to use a table heading different from the element name? E.g. something like:

```
<xs:element name="place-of-origin">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo><od:displayName>Place of origin</od:displayName></xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

**Edit:** here's a [sample XML file](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/351642/) and [corresponding XSD](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/351645/). Opening this in Excel yields a table with a column heading “sex_of_person” — so the question is: how can the XML or schema express that this heading should be “sex of person” (with spaces), or “#$!%” (excuse me), or any other string not valid as an [XML name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name)?

Comment: Could you please add a sample intermediate Xml data?

Comment: Added, along with a tiny bit of elaboration.

Comment: Have you considered / are you happy to use an XSL transformation? Are is there some reason you're avoiding that option?

Comment: How would that help? Even if Excel did obey a processing instruction to apply XSLT, the transformation would just produce another XML document, and so the restriction on element names would still apply.

Answer (score 0):

You say you use your XML as a "data-source" thereby using the XML-functionality of Excel (beginning with version 2003).

When you open an XML-file in Excel, Excel offers you the option to transform it into a readable form (and giving you the option to automatically infere an XML-schema).

Once you have done this, Excel has -- in the background -- 'used' the XML-file (and the implicitly generated XML-schema, but you can use your excisting schema) as an XML-Source.

[image: Excel 2007 with opened XML-file and XML-source]

From now on for Excel the column title can be changed (Excel has an internal way to link sex_of_person from the XML file to the second column of the table).
[image: List with changed column headers]

To demonstrate this I have in my example deleted all the lines except one. Note how Excel selects the second row "Sex of person" (*without* the header) when I choose "sex_of_person" in the XML pane. Now when I click refresh (in my german version: "Daten aktualisieren") Excel reloads the XML file and inserts the values in the corresponding columns. Using "Import" you can even change the XML source (provided that the format stays the same).

So from now on I don't open the XML file in Excel (as you possibly have done) but I open this Excel-file that from now on defines the presentation (i.e. links from XML-element to a column) and includes the link to the XML-file.

I am not absolutely sure this is what you meant.

Regards
Andreas

Comment: Right, that's not what I meant. I am not the Excel user, I am the provider of the XML data feed. I want the *initial* appearance to the user to be as close to the source data as possible.

Comment: Is there no way for you to provide the Excel (something like 'the frontend' for your XML source) for the user? She would open the Excel-sheet and refresh the import. OR: What about creating the Excel-file on the server (e.g. generating Office Open XML Format)?